# Exit status of process not good in case of error

Tags: c, process, fork, wait, waitpid

I have a problem regarding of mini program that will return me the exit status of my child process in case of error occuring during execve.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int main ()
{
    char *argv[] = {"ls",NULL};
    char *envp[] = {NULL};
    int status;
    int pid;
    int err;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execve("/usr/bin/lds", argv, envp);
        perror("error");
        
    }
    else
    {
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    printf("%d\n", status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
        err = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    exit(status);
    }
}
```

The above code is just demo to make me understand how process exit status work, the problem is when when I put a wrong path such /usr/bin/lds the status code print is 0 while an error occured in my child process, while when a command is not found in bash the status code sent back is 127 my question is how to make it return 127 as bash does when  a bad command is entered ?

Comment: Put `exit(127);` after `perror()`.  You may want to distinguish between “not found” and “not executable”.  Then you have to look at the error number after the `execve()` fails.  Since you don't modify the environment, you could/should use `execv()`.

Comment: I thought this would be set automatically by the wait pid, but i do that would not the other status error code that may happen be missed because of my program always returning 127 ?

Comment: No: the status reported by `waitpid()` is simply the child's exit status or the signal information.  If the child dies because it is signalled, the shell maps that to`128 + signal`.  You have to manage that, too.

Answer (score 0):

[exec(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) family functions return `-1` on failure. So you can't get the shell's return code.

Your code current returns 0 for child's status because you're not returning anything on error
and thus the child process returns 0 exiting main.

You could instead do:

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    int r = execve("/usr/bin/dls", argv, envp);
    perror("error");
    exit(r);
}
```

You can also inspect errno and return specific values from the child to parent:

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    int r = execve("/usr/bin/dls", argv, envp);
    exit(errno);
}
```

And the parent can inspect child's return code and print appropriate message or return value.

Alternatively you can map the errno values returned by `execve` to shell's return values and then return those values yourself so that it matches shell's return value.

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    int r = execve("/usr/bin/dls", argv, envp);
    if (errno == ENOENT)
        exit(127);
    else if (errno == ...)
    /* and so on */
}
```

This is more work for little benefit. Typically you
only need to know when exec failed and not exactly what shell returned on failure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is only for my school homework where I have to return status code as well

Comment: I am fairly sure your school work actually meant the return value of the *command* executed by the child when exec succeeded, not specific shell exit code when exec failed. It should be enough to return -1 from child on exec failure. You can clarify this with your staff/school before choosing more complex approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The exit status sent from a program to the host environment is:

- If the program calls `exit`, `_Exit`, or `quickexit`, the value passed to that routine.
- If the program calls `abort`, an implementation-defined unsuccessful termination.
- If the initial call to `main` executes `return`, the value given in the `return` statement.
- If execution of the initial call to `main` flows to its terminating `}`, zero.

`waitpid` does none of these and does not affect the program exit status. To send 127 for the exit status to the host environment, you should execute `exit(127)` or `return 127;` after `perror("error");` or at the end of `main`.